# Using Generics in Typescript with Arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

In Typescript, if I'm defining a type that stipulates only strings can go into an array, I'm able to define that like this:

`type stringArray = string[]`

I'm able to specify that certain kinds of objects may go into an array like this:

```
type myObject  = { 
    one: string,
    two: string,
}
type objectArray = myObject[]
```

However, I'm able to accomplish something very similar with generics, like this:

`type stringArray = Array<string>`

and

`type objectArray = Array<myObject>`

**Is there any advantage to using either approach? When should one use the former and when is the latter a better approach?**

Comment: iirc, the bracket syntax is just some sugar, since it looks cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array<T>` and `T[]` are 100% equivalent.

Which to use is mostly a code style choice. Though the `T[]` syntax is usually preferred in most codebases that I've seen as it *looks* like an array, and at a glance it is shorter.